# Deriving all employees from table having department id starting with 250 and 270?

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

I am using SQL plus with oracle 10.2.0.1.0. I wanted to retrieve employees who are having the department (deptid- varchar2) numbers starting with '270', '250' from the ps_job table which has more fields also.

This is the query that i have written-

select distinct deptid from ps_job 
where deptid in ('250%', '270%');

It shows no rows, if i remove distinct, it gives me plenty of results with duplicate results also.

Answer (score 1):

`in` doesn't accept wildcards.  Do this:

```
select distinct deptid from ps_job 
where (deptid like '250%'
       or deptid like '270%');
```

Alternatively:

```
select distinct deptid from ps_job 
where substr(deptid,1,3) in ('250', '270');
```

That won't use an index on deptid though, whereas the first version might (but might not).

Comment: Why distinct deptid and not employeeid? - what if an employeeid is part of both deptid's?

Comment: I don't know - it wasn't my question!

Answer (score 0):

What i did that i break down the query in 2 different queries. 1 for 250 and other for 270 and i used LIKE, previously is used IN, but somehow it didn't work correctly.

select distinct deptid from ps_job
where deptid LIKE '250%';

select distinct deptid from ps_job
where deptid LIKE '250%';

And Bob, as far as your concern goes, our DB does not have such provision as we work with effective dates and sequence, so it pretty makes sure that employee has 1 dept id currently.